# mysql select name and total name column count

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

EDITED for a better example:

I'm trying to get a list of DISTINCT names and the total column count of these distinct names, not each name count but the column. Like so:

```
id  |  date        | name
----|--------------|--------
1   |  2017-06-23  |  Peter
2   |  2017-06-23  |  Sue
3   |  2017-06-23  |  Mag
4   |  2017-06-23  |  Sue
5   |  2017-06-23  |  Paul
6   |  2017-06-23  |  Paul
7   |  2017-06-23  |  Sue
```

Expected result would be in individual arrays `ORDER BY name DESC` and `limit 3:`

```
MAG 
PAUL 
Peter 
3
```

The total count would be the limit if query exceeds or, a total count if query does not exceed the limit.

***SOLUTION***
Since it seems to be hard to achieve the expected results in one mysql query I opted by a simpler and faster solution that will aslo cut down the mysql query time.

Query
    SELECT DISTINCT name FROM my table ORDER by name DESC LIMIT 3;

Since I was going to use php foreach to manipulate the results, I just counted the names inside the foreach.

```
$count_names = 0;

foreach($name as $count ){

$my code to manipulate names;

$count_names++;
}
echo $count_names; Gives me the total names.
```

The query LIMIT is used because it's a huge db updated daily, probably the limit will be 1000 and the $count_ip's will return 1000. But if the daily name update is smaller than 1000 the query returns a smaller value than the LIMIT and the $count_ips will return the correct smaller name count.
Thanks

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name), COUNT(DISTINCT name) ...

Comment: Thanks strawberry, It does not give me the correct results of: Peter->Sue->Mag->Paul->4... instead it gives me: Peter->1Sue->1Mag->1Paul->1

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets. They have no order other than that defined by an ORDER BY expression.

Comment: You are not clear. Please edit your question: What exact example table value do you want? Exactly how does the output look in terms of the input for an arbitrary case? What are these arrows? Are they part of an output string? Be very clear.

Comment: Please use block/code format for your tables. Look at the formatted output below the text edit window. What does "individual arrays" mean? Array in what language? A string? If this is a table, give column name(s). Please be absolutely clear. Your last line is not clear. Use enough sentences and words to clearly say what you mean. Don't just write a few words that would be part of a clear exposition.

Comment: Please refresh your browser because I already rolled back all your changes because they addded nothing and made the formatting worse from what fortune did. And you have still not made content changes per my comments. Be clear. Use enough words. Please read and act on [mcve] *like you were told when you posted*. You could also give SQL that prints out the particular output of your example so at least we'd know what it's supposed to be since words haven't been working.

Comment: I am just trying to find out what you want, because you are not clear. Rather than writing sarcasm, read the mouseover text for the downvote arrow & [ask]. Good luck.

Comment: It's clear... would be nice to see if someone else comes along and finds it clear. The trouble and waisted time I went through with your unhelpful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find it easier  and mysql light.

```
$count_names = 0;

foreach($name as $count ){

$my code to manipulate names;

$count_names++;
}
echo $count_names; Gives me the total names.
```

Comment: Tip for future questions you may have: if a non-SQL-query-based answer is acceptable to an SQL query question, you should state that explicitly in your question. Otherwise if you answer your own question with something outside the boundaries of what you were asking, you risk your question being flagged by the SO mods, and nobody wants that :D

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:

```
set @num = 0;
SELECT name FROM (
    SELECT name, @num := @num + 1 AS num
    FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY name
        ORDER BY name
        LIMIT 3
    ) AS a
    UNION
    SELECT @num as name, @num AS num
) AS b
```

(Here's an example using a variation on the [SQL fiddle from fortune's answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac146/80))

As to *why* you want to do that... *shrug* :)

Note, if you're doing this in a real RDBMS and you don't like all the trickery with variables and inner select statements and unions, you can just do the inner select (the one with the limit on it) and return all the results there, but use the language's "resultset size" feature (eg: rowCount(), num_results, whatever) to get your last row which would be the total number.

Comment: Good answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this is what you want:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name), COUNT(DISTINCT name) from table;
```

Ref: Comments from strawberry, and Tik

***UPDATE***

```
(SELECT DISTINCT(name) from table ORDER BY name LIMIT 3)
  UNION 
(SELECT IF(COUNT(DISTINCT(name)) > 3, 3, COUNT(DISTINCT(name)))  FROM table )
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac146/63)

Comment: Hi and thanks... no this is not giving the total of the column name SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(name)), COUNT(DISTINCT name) from table gives me: Peter->1 Sue->1 Mag->1 Paul->1 and not Mag Peter Sue 4

Comment: As per your request, this is yielding, see here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb004/3

Comment: Ow finally.... it does give the 4 names and the total. the only issue now is that it creates 2 arrays (names... coma separated) and Total. Is it possible to split the first array into 4 arrays 1 per name + the total array? Also how do group by name, order by name DESC and limit to 0,1000 in the future?

Comment: Might be something like :

SELECT DISTINCT(name), (select count(DISTINCT name) from table) from table;

Comment: The question isn't clear. Don't guess, tell the op they're not clear & tell them to edit their question.

Comment: I am trying to help you but I am not sure this is what you want

Comment: @fortune, thanks for your help. Thinking about just queting the query of name without count. After the query will use php foreach to count. Will post back tomorrow. Thanks again.